# Fl Chart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, fl-chart

I'm using fl chart and I want to make a chart where LeftTitle and RightTitle will be independent of each other. Now I set maxY and minY and it immediately works on the right and left sides. Is it possible to make them independent of each other? [image: Almost like the picture]

I try to change minY and maxY but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

This code may be helpful, please check here:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Independent Axes Chart'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: IndependentAxesChart(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IndependentAxesChart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create data for both left and right axes
    List<FlSpot> leftData = [
      const FlSpot(0, 5),
      const FlSpot(1, 10),
      const FlSpot(2, 15),
      const FlSpot(3, 20),
    ];

    List<FlSpot> rightData = [
      const FlSpot(0, 100),
      const FlSpot(1, 200),
      const FlSpot(2, 300),
      const FlSpot(3, 400),
    ];

    return LineChart(
      LineChartData(
        gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
        titlesData: const FlTitlesData(
          leftTitles: AxisTitles(
            sideTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: true,
              reservedSize: 28,
            ),
          ),
          rightTitles: AxisTitles(
            sideTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: true,
              reservedSize: 28,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        borderData: FlBorderData(
          show: true,
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d), width: 1),
        ),
        minX: 0,
        maxX: 3,
        minY: 0, // Set your left axis minimum here
        maxY: 25, // Set your left axis maximum here

        lineBarsData: [
          LineChartBarData(
            spots: leftData,
            isCurved: true,
            color: Colors.blue,
            dotData: const FlDotData(show: false),
            belowBarData: BarAreaData(show: false),
          ),
          LineChartBarData(
            spots: rightData,
            isCurved: true,
            color: Colors.red,
            dotData: const FlDotData(show: false),
            belowBarData: BarAreaData(show: false),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you explain to Rapkat why your code is helpful? Posting just code without any context is not very useful as the idea of for him and everyone else to understand the solution.

Comment: Thank you Harsh Patel, but your solution not solve my problem. I run your code and left and right titles are same.

Comment: I solve my problem by using Stack. I used two Charts, in first chart I displayed leftTitle and in second I displayed rightTitle.

Comment: yeah, Rapkat Baudunov OKay Thanks